# Disabling a S3 Lifecycle Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've some s3 lifecycle rules in place that transition objects from S3 Storage Class Standard to Glacier. Due to some recent changes in the compliance policy at my workplace, when I tried to disable a rule, I got the below message which I don't understand clearly.

```
You are about to disable a lifecycle rule that may start automated transitions to a lower-priced storage tier, which may impact your costs.
```

Does this in any way mean that the objects which are already on Glacier will be moved back to S3?

Any clarity into this would be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling a lifecycle rule does not change anything about any objects already modified/processed by that rule.

Disabling the rule "may impact your costs" because it will -- in the future -- no longer be able to move future objects to a lower cost tier... so you will pay more in the future for objects of which the rule might otherwise have lowered the cost, had it remained in place.